# Quick and reliable HTTP call from PHP script

Tags: php

I am adding some external HTTP calls (for internal status monitoring) to a large PHP application which is already very complex and prone to errors. The HTTP call should be made quickly and without raising errors/exceptions. It is okay for HTTP calls to fail.

My first thought was to use Curl but it is not installed on the server. This would let me supress errors, set timeouts and prevent unnecessary blocking if the status server is unreachable/slow.

I know of several built-in PHP functions which can make an HTTP request (and these are enabled on the server) - `file()`, `file_get_contents()`, `http-get()` and I can prefix it with `@` to suppress errors. But if the monitoring server is unreachable it will hang the script for a number of seconds. Is there a way to set a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a timeout, as the [documentation/comments of file_get_content](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) says:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array( 
    'http' => array( 
        'timeout' => 1 
    ) 
)); 

file_get_contents("http://example.com/", 0, $ctx);
```

Comment: and even set it after the stream is created with stream_set_timeout

Comment: Thanks! `file_get_contents()` was delayed by over 30 seconds by default. With your answer it successfully timeouts after 1 second with a Warning which I can suppress with `@`

Comment: Just discovered the timeout setting here is in *seconds* but it will accept a *float* value (for example `'timeout' => 0.5` for 500ms) as documented in the [context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)